# Is it possible to do a vlookup searching for the first 8 characters and the last 2 characters?

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup, lookup, excel-2016

Sorry in advance for any errors in the post as i am new. Basically i am trying to do a vlook up searching for the first 8 characters and the last 2 characters of a single string ie. (20.5/020/025/IE). I have separated what i need by a left and right formula  as shown and that works right and the result is as shown under

```
 =LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)+3)& RIGHT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-2)
         First 8         Last 2   
  Result 20.5/010/       IE

  What im searching 20.5/020/025/IE
```

Now i have no clue how to do a partial vlookup to match values that starts with the first 8 and ends in last 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATCH allows the use of wildcards, so use something like this:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("THIS IS " & "*" & "CC",A:A,0))
```

[image]

Comment: =INDEX(B2,MATCH(H2 & "*" & I2,A2:C123,0))     this is what i currently have and it is not working for me, Maybe i am doing the formula wrong. The cell B2 for me is where i wanna to match it, H2 is the begining of the word and I2 is the end of it. The rest then is the columns i am referencing any idea why its not working

Comment: @dave yes, Match must only reference the column in which you want to search, 1 column or 1 row, not a 2 dimensional range.  The first reference in Match is what to find,  The first range in the INDEX is the output range.

Comment: =INDEX(B2,MATCH("20.5/010/" & "*" & I2,A2:C123,0)) i have changed it to one cell and it is still not working for me

Comment: Index should be a range, match must be only one column or one row.

Comment: If you look at mine you will see that I am referring to full column ranges.

Comment: Kind of a beginner at this and honestly don't know what you mean by the index should be a range, which area are you talking about ? sorry for being very stupid in this area

Comment: Ill give it a go for an hour or so and see if i can sort it thanks for your help

Comment: Look at my formula and my setup.  Column B is the desired output, and as such I am referring to it in the INDEX.  Column A is the lookup column and as such I refer to it in MATCH.

Comment: =INDEX(B:B,MATCH("20.5/010/" & "*" & I2,A:C,0))    still no luck even with this

Comment: MATCH **CANNOT** refer to multiple columns.  It is either `A:A` or `B:B` or `C:C` **NOT** `A:C`  Which ever column has your lookup information.